# Is there a jQuery grid that even comes close to the ExtJs GridPanel in terms of looks and functionality?

Tags: jquery, extjs

I've taken a look at the jQuery grid recommendations made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations) but these don't seem to compare to the sleekness of the [ExtJs GridPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/row-editing.html).

Has anyone styled one of these implementations to make them appear a bit more like the ExtJs grid more or less?  Or are there some other choices here that aren't captured in the link above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no. The ExtJs CSS, images and javascript files since 2.1 have been released under the dual GPL / commercial license. There's nothing that does quite what the ExtJs grid does.

This notable fact has been made clear by the authors of FlexiGrid, one of the closest mimics: "One of my main goal for the plugin is ultimately to keep it lightweight, maybe under 20k when compressed. Because otherwise you should probably stick with Ext Grid or YUI data table."

Comment: another thing to note is that FlexiGrid's last release was :1.0b3 (Released 14 July 2008). ExtJs has released a minor and a major version since then.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe jqGrid is the best choice. It has a lot of features, independent data/view layers, templating, etc. Also uses jquery UI framework for UI, so can be easily integrated in jquery ui based project
http://www.trirand.com/blog/